# Not able to resolve jPOS latest version 2.0.8?

Tags: jpos

I was trying to resolve jPOS:2.0.8 version but it is failing because not able to resolve dependency for com.sleepycat.je:je:7.0.6.

```
<dependency>
<groupId>com.sleepycat</groupId>
<artifactId>je</artifactId>
<version>7.0.6</version>
<scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

I have check the maven repository and com.sleepycat.je lower version is available there.

http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/sleepycat/je/
http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/jpos/jpos/2.0.8/jpos-2.0.8.pom

Edit
Even i have added `maven { url 'download.oracle.com/maven'; }` in build.gradle but still not resolving the dependency.

Edit :
I am getting below error

> - What went wrong: Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':compileClasspath'.
>
>   > Could not resolve com.sleepycat:je:7.0.6.   Required by:
>   >     org.jpos:jpos:2.0.8
>   >     Could not resolve com.sleepycat:je:7.0.6.
>   >     Could not get resource 'http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/sleepycat/je/7.0.6/je-7.0.6.pom'.
>   >     Could not GET 'http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/sleepycat/je/7.0.6/je-7.0.6.pom'.
>   >     Connect to repo.maven.apache.org:80 [repo.maven.apache.org/151.101.20.215] failed: Connection timed out:
>   >     connect
>   >     Could not resolve com.sleepycat:je:7.0.6.
>   >     Could not get resource 'http://jpos.org/maven/com/sleepycat/je/7.0.6/je-7.0.6.pom'.
>   >     Could not GET 'http://jpos.org/maven/com/sleepycat/je/7.0.6/je-7.0.6.pom'.
>   >     Connect to jpos.org:80 [jpos.org/52.7.83.125] failed: Connection timed out: connect
>   >     Could not resolve com.sleepycat:je:7.0.6.
>   >     Could not get resource 'http://download.oracle.com/maven/com/sleepycat/je/7.0.6/je-7.0.6.pom'.
>   >     Could not GET 'http://download.oracle.com/maven/com/sleepycat/je/7.0.6/je-7.0.6.pom'.
>   >     Connect to download.oracle.com:80 [download.oracle.com/23.50.225.25, download.oracle.com/23.50.225.9]
>   >     failed: Connection timed out: connect
> - Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

Answer (score 5):

sleepycat version 7.0.6 is not in the main maven repo, you need to add oracle maven repo to your pom:

```
  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>oracleReleases</id>
      <name>Oracle Released Java Packages</name>
      <url>http://download.oracle.com/maven</url>
      <layout>default</layout>
    </repository>
  </repositories>
```

This goes outside the dependencies tag, directly under de project tag.

Comment: http://download.oracle.com/maven

I have tried to access above link and it is giving "404 : We're sorry, the page you requested was not found."

Comment: Even i have added maven { url 'http://download.oracle.com/maven' } i build.gradle but still not resolving the dependency.

Comment: I fail to reproduce your problem, can you shere your build.gradle or your pom.xm and the output it gives when you run it?

Comment: when I run gradle jar in a jpos dependant project gradle is able to download the pom and the jar:

    :compileJava
    Download http://download.oracle.com/maven/com/sleepycat/je/7.0.6/je-7.0.6.pom
    Download http://download.oracle.com/maven/com/sleepycat/je/7.0.6/je-7.0.6.jar
    :compileJava UP-TO-DATE
    :processResources NO-SOURCE
    :classes UP-TO-DATE
    :jar UP-TO-DATE

    BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Comment: The error 404  when opening the url is because the server doesn't allow access directly to the directory

Comment: Build.gradle entry repositories { maven { url "repo.maven.apache.org/maven2"; } maven { url 'jpos.org/maven'; } maven { url 'download.oracle.com/maven'; } } dependencies { compile 'org.jpos:jpos:2.0.8' }

Comment: Or for Gradle `maven { url 'http://download.oracle.com/maven' } // to resolve com.sleepycat:je dependency`

Answer (score 5):

Add this code in pom.xml

```html
<repositories>
  <repository>
  <id>oracle</id>
  <name>Oracle repo</name>
  <url>http://download.oracle.com/maven</url>
  </repository>
</repositories>
```

Answer (score 5):

Or You could ignore sleepy cat dependency

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.jpos</groupId>
<artifactId>jpos</artifactId>
<version>2.1.0</version>
<exclusions>
  <exclusion>
  <groupId>com.sleepycat</groupId>
  <artifactId>je</artifactId>
  </exclusion>
</exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score -1):

Just use jpos 1.9.2. Thats the last stable release eitherway

Comment: sorry but latest jpos release is [2.1.2] (https://github.com/jpos/jPOS/releases/tag/v2_1_2)